# Remove / replace object from group in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i'm trying to replace an SVG from a group (or delete and add a new one) but it's not working. Those are the ways I already tried:

```
var group = new fabric.Group([svg, text], {options});

canvas.remove(svg); // not working

group.getObjects()[0] = my_new_svg; // not working

group.forEachObject(function(o) { // not working
    if (is_svg_object) {
        canvas.remove(o);
    }
});
```

I been using `version 1.6.4` and it's working really fine. But now, i'm migrating to the latest release `1.7.17` and have this issues.

I notice also that in this release, I cannot set a property directly, I be forced to use the method.

```
object.setTextBackgroundColor(color); // works

object.textBackgroundColor = color; // works in 1.6, not in 1.7.17
```

So i'm thinking this issue can be related.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to take in account lately on 1.7.x onward.

1) you get object caching as default. That means that fabric will paint the object just when something change.
you should read this until it makes sense, if it doesnt ask to clarify better the explanations:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching

2) To make the changes effective you can solve in 3 ways:

use the setter method as you described ( better in the `.set('textBackgroundColor', color)` version )

flag the object as dirty after the changes ( object.set('dirty', true) )

disable objectCaching ( not suggested )

3) The correct way to remove an object from a Group is

```
var group = new fabric.Group([svg, text], {options});

group.remove(svg);

group.addWithUpdate(my_new_svg);

group.moveTo(my_new_svg, 0);
```

To be honest see what is not working and why would grant you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi, I can solve this isue, i had to refactor some things, but most of them were related to the new way to set properties and the object caching! I need to take a review to the 1.7 release notes!! Thanks :)

Comment: Start directly with the 2.0 beta at this point if you are not in critical production environment.

Comment: Ok, I will take your advice, did you said that there is not big difference (in compatibility) between 1.7.X and beta 2? Thanks

Comment: between 1.6 and 1.7 you find issues like jumping on 2.0. Give it at shot. I m writing more migration docs this weekend

Comment: Great!! Thanks, some day i would like to collaborate with the project, I really love fabric. Should I take the latest beta version (4) or just the beta 1, which one your recommend?

Comment: take latest master, build it, keep an eye daily to see bugs or new commits. i m working on t on a daily basis trying to get a 2.0 stable asap. stable means not without bugs, just with a good api and docs.